# VAR model: include all lags up to AIC-suggested order or just the significant ones?

Tags: model-selection, aic, vector-autoregression, lags

I'm building a regression model in which I have a dependent variable OSE, and two independent variables, MSCI and Brent.
In this model I wish to include lagged variables. I performed an AIC for my model: I ran a VAR lag-order selection pre-estimation with all the three as dependent variables. It tells me the optimal lag for the model is 2.

Does this mean I should include all the lag levels of the variables to my regression, or just keep the significant ones?

Comment: *I performed AIC for my model* sounds weird, but I did not dear to rephrase it when editing.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose AIC corresponds to the model with full lags rather than just the significant ones (correct me if I am wrong), so what it is telling you directly regards models with full lags. Whether kicking out the insignificant ones will improve the model is an empirical question. Note that you can also obtain AIC for the model once you have removed the insignificant lags. Then you can see whether removing those lags worked in terms of AIC reduction.

Generally, AIC is useful, but it does not perform well if you consider a very large pool of models. See e.g. Hansen ["A winner’s curse for econometric models: on the joint distribution of in-sample fit and out-of-sample fit and its implications for model selection"](http://www.tse-fr.eu/sites/default/files/medias/stories/SEMIN_10_11/ECONOMETRIE/hansen.pdf) (2010).

Comment: AIC just tells how many not the lag length. Any subset of lagged variables could be searched.

Comment: Agree with the second sentence, cannot quite follow the first sentence.